# Bootstrap 3, input group not responsive. Please guide

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[1]Bootstrap 3, input group is not showing properly in mobile. 
Please look at the code below. It appears perfectly on my macbook but on my iphone the input box does not appear fully and the search box appears on the next line.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 ">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 ">
    <div>
      <!--<form class="form-inline" role="form"  method="post" action="/reviews">-->
      <form method="POST" action="http://exelrate.dev/reviews" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="t1eHqUE5XYCkmSIYigI0q7RcXwPe265d7x1HyFRc">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon" style="min-width:110px;">Location</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control "  id="mapsearch" name="mapsearch" placeholder="Enter City,Pin or Address" 
              style="height:43px; min-width:402px; font-size:1.0em;" required/>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
              <select id="carmodel" class="form-control input-sm" style="min-width:200px;" required="required" name="size">
                <option value="Car" selected="selected">Car</option>
                <option value="2-Wheeler">2-Wheeler</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" name="input_lat" id="input_lat" required>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" name="input_lng" id="input_lng" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_search" style="width:200px;height:42px;">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ8m4.png [mobile site]

Comment: You have a `min-width` assigned to it.

Comment: Show a snapshot then it would be easy to help

Answer (score 1):

Your inline styling affects Bootstrap. Also, you made some common Bootstrap mistakes:

- placed an `input-group` inside a `form-group` (this is not a biggie but I had alignment issues with it in some browser versions - avoid if possible).
- placed multiple inputs in one `input-group`. don't do it, even if only one is `type="text"` and the rest are hidden.
- you don't need an empty column for offseting. use the offseting classes from Bootstrap (`col-md-offset-1` in your case).

Here's a fixed version of your form:

**NOTE**: You don't need the CSS (`form {margin: 15px;}`) rule, I just added it for the stack**overflow** snippet.

```css
form {
  margin: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  form .hidden-xs {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div>
      <!--<form class="form-inline" role="form"  method="post" action="/reviews">-->
      <form method="POST" action="http://exelrate.dev/reviews" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-inline">

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="t1eHqUE5XYCkmSIYigI0q7RcXwPe265d7x1HyFRc">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon hidden-xs">Location</div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mapsearch" name="mapsearch" placeholder="Enter City,Pin or Address" style="min-height:44px;" required/>
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <select id="carmodel" class="selectpicker form-control input-sm" required="required" name="size" style="min-width: 120px">
              <option value="Car" selected="selected">Car</option>
              <option value="2-Wheeler">2-Wheeler</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" name="input_lat" id="input_lat" required>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" name="input_lng" id="input_lng" required>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_search" style="min-width:200px;height:42px; margin-top: 15px;">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed very helpful, since stackoverflow did not allow me to add another screenshot, I could not show how it appears in my website. The button search is actually next to the dropdown "ca/2-wheeler" on desktop version, would that be a good idea to have? and how to achieve this with responsive code.

Comment: Normally, you can hide things on mobiles using `.hidden-xs`. Unfortunatelly, this adds `display: block !important;` to those elements on devices wider than 768px. To overcome this for `input-group-addon`s you need to add `display: table-cell !important` for `.hidden-xs` above 768px. Updated answer.

Comment: Well, that has nearly resolved my issue. However, after removing the width property in style, the input items are no longer full width in my desktop. My mobile version seems to look wonderful but desktop version is now shrink-ed to half almost. Any suggestions, what might be wrong ?